# AjaxFileUpload validation

Tags: asp.net

I am uploading multiple files using `AjaxFileUpload` and zipping all of them on submit button to a destination folder.

Now I need to validate if the zip file already exists in destination folder and show message on submit button, and allow the user to change the zipfile name.

Tried `UploadStart`, `OnUploadComplete`, `UploadCompleteAll` but could not achieve.

Comment: check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1207741/Ajax-File-Upload-With-Client-Side-Validation

Comment: using ajaxfileupload not asyncfileupload